# Pushing app with AdMob integration to public github

Tags: java, android, admob

Hi I've got an open source app that is on Github. I have just integrated Admob, thus i needed to put my Admob ad id into the code. I still want to keep the app open source, but im aware that the ad id must be kept private. How could i push the app to github without others being able to see the ad unit id?

Would it be enough to simply remove the id from the following line prior to pushing the code?:

```
ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your adUnitId private, then yes you could remove the id from your published code.